# How to remove CSS animation from element in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, css

I've got a square grid of n x n smaller square div elements that I want to illuminate in a sequence with a CSS background color animation. I have a function to generate a random array for the sequence. The trouble I'm having is that once a certain square has been illuminated once, if it occurs again within the array it won't illuminate a second time. I believe it's because once the element has been assigned the CSS animation, the animation can't trigger again on that element, and I can't figure a way to make it work. It's for a Responsive Web Apps course I'm taking, and the assessment stipulates that we're only to use vanilla JS, and that all elements must be created in JS and appended to a blank `<body>` in our index.html.

Each flash according to the sequence is triggered through a setTimeout function that loops through all elements in the array increasing it's timer by 1s for each loop (the animation length is 1s also).

Defining containers and child divs:

```
function createGameContainer(n, width, height) {
    var container = document.createElement('div');

    //CSS styling
    container.style.margin = '50px auto'
    container.style.width = width;
    container.style.height = height;
    container.style.display = 'grid';

    // loop generates string to create necessary number of grid columns based on the width of the grid of squares
    var columns = '';
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        columns += ' calc(' + container.style.width + '/' + n.toString() + ')'
    }
    container.style.gridTemplateColumns = columns;

    container.style.gridRow = 'auto auto';

    // gap variable to reduce column and row gap for larger grid sizes
    // if n is ever set to less than 2, gap is hardcoded to 20 to avoid taking square root of 0 or a negative value
    var gap;
    if (n > 1) {
        gap = 20/Math.sqrt(n-1);
    } else {
        gap = 20;
    }

    container.style.gridColumnGap = gap.toString() + 'px';
    container.style.gridRowGap = gap.toString() + 'px';

    container.setAttribute('id', 'game-container');

    document.body.appendChild(container);
}


/*
function to create individual squares to be appended to parent game container
*/
function createSquare(id) {
    var square = document.createElement('div');

    //CSS styling
    square.style.backgroundColor = '#333';
    //square.style.padding = '20px';
    square.style.borderRadius = '5px';
    square.style.display = 'flex';
    square.style.alignItems = 'center';
    //set class and square id
    square.setAttribute('class', 'square');
    square.setAttribute('id', id);

    return square;
}
/*
function to create game container and and squares and append squares to parent container
parameter n denotes dimensions of game grid - n x n grid
*/

function createGameWindow(n, width, height) {
    window.dimension = n;
    createGameContainer(n, width, height);

    /*
    loop creates n**2 number of squares to fill game container and assigns an id to each square from 0 at the top left square to (n**2)-1 at the bottom right square
    */
    for (i = 0; i < n**2; i++) {
        var x = createSquare(i);
        document.getElementById('game-container').appendChild(x);
    }
}
```

The CSS animation:

```
@keyframes flash {
    0% {
        background: #333;
    }

    50% {
        background: orange
    }

    100% {
        background: #333;
    }
}

.flashing {
    animation: flash 1s;
}
```

The code to generate the array:

```
function generateSequence(sequenceLength) {
    var sequence = [];
    for (i = 0; i < sequenceLength; i++) {
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (dimension**2));
        // the following loop ensures each element in the sequence is different than the previous element
        while (sequence[i-1] == random) {
            random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (dimension**2));
        }
        sequence[i] = random;
    };

    return sequence;
}
```

Code to apply animation to square:

```
function flash(index, delay) {
    setTimeout( function() {
        flashingSquare = document.getElementById(index);
        flashingSquare.style.animation = 'flashOne 1s';
        flashingSquare.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
            flashingSquare.style.animation = '';
    }, delay);    
}
```

I've also tried removing and adding a class again to try and reset the animation:

```
function flash(index, delay) {
    setTimeout( function() {
        flashingSquare = document.getElementById(index);
        flashingSquare.classList.remove('flashing');
        flashingSquare.classList.add('flashing');
    }, delay);    
}
```

And the function to generate and display the sequence:

```
function displaySequence(sequenceLength) {
    var sequence = generateSequence(sequenceLength);

    i = 0;
    while (i < sequence.length) {
        index = sequence[i].toString();
        flash(index, i*1000);

        i++;
    }
}
```

Despite many different attempts and a bunch of research I can't figure a way to get the animations to trigger multiple times on the same element.

Comment: Hi Andrew and a warm welcome to SO :) Where is your definition of DIV's?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
function flash(index, delay){
    setTimeout( function() {
        flashingSquare = document.getElementById(index);
        flashingSquare.classList.add('flashing');
        flashingSquare.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
                flashingSquare.classList.remove('flashing');
        }, delay);    
    });
}
```

Don't remove the animation, **remove the class**.

Remove the class **direct AFTER** the animation is done. So the browser have time to handle everything to do so. And when you add the class **direct BEFORE** you want the animation, the browser can trigger all needed steps to do so.

Your attempt to remove and add the class was good but to fast. I think the browser and the DOM optimize your steps and do nothing.

Comment: Thanks Marcus, I added the code for creating the container and divs.
I tried that solution but when I run now all of the squares illuminate at once, and I'm not sure why. Thanks for your answer though!

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I figured out a work around. I rewrote the function so that the setTimeout was nested within a for loop, and the setTimeout nested within an immediately invoked function expression (which I still don't fully understand, but hey, if it works). The new function looks like this:

```
/*
function to display game sequence
length can be any integer greater than 1
speed is time between flashes in ms and can presently be set to 1000, 750, 500 and 250.
animation length for each speed is set by a corresponding speed class
in CSS main - .flashing1000 .flashing750 .flashing500 and .flashing250
*/
function displaySequence(length, speed) {
    var sequence = generateSequence(length);
    console.log(sequence);

    for (i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++) {
        console.log(sequence[i]);
        //       immediately invoked function expression
        (function(i) {
            setTimeout( function () {
                var sq = document.getElementById(sequence[i]);
                sq.classList.add('flashing' + speed.toString());
                sq.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
                    sq.classList.remove('flashing' + speed.toString());
                })
            }, (speed * i))
        })(i);
    }
}
```

the CSS for each class:

```
@keyframes flash {
    0% {
        background: #333;
    }

    50% {
        background: orange
    }

    100% {
        background: #333;
    }
}

.flashing1000 {
    animation: flash 975ms;
}

.flashing750 {
    animation: flash 725ms;
}

.flashing500 {
    animation: flash 475ms;
}

.flashing250 {
    animation: flash 225ms;
}
```

A few lazy work arounds, I know, but it works well enough.